#  Error Using MathFP class in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I am tryin to develop a game in j2m using eclipse. To handle floating point I have downloaded the MathFp class. I did the following steps
i placed the mathFP.class file in net/jscience/math/kvm/ directory
1> Ziped the folder containig the downloaded class.
2> java build path->libraries->ADD jar->selected my zipped  folder.
3> in the source code of my project i wrote import net.jscience.math.kvm.MathFP;

But when i compile it it shows `NoClassDefFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the relevant jar is checked in the "Java Build Path" -> "Order and Export" window.

Comment: Yea. i did that.but its showing this error.......................Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Preverification' on project 'Carrom'.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getTarget(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;